# How can I know if the user drew 8 number

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'll create a drawing app and I want to show a message to the user if he draws 8 number, How can I do that.

What class or method name should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any class or method to do what you want. You may want to take a look at machine learning or libraries to analyse images.

Once the user finished drawing, you get the view as an image and process it (using a library or something like that).

Comment: I'll look at Firebase ML , Thank You

Comment: I'd look at handwriting analysis libraries.  Luckily that's a fairly well researched field.  But you probably wouldn't get the view as an image, it probably would be more accurate with streams of touch events.